# Group of related functions that require the same expensive setup

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently am porting some code from c++ to python that requires loading a very big file into memory and doing some expensive setup operations before it can be used. The code makes use of a large lookup table to speed up the execution time for a **group** of time-critical related functions (over 5 functions use this same table extensively). I think this situation is somewhat nicely dealt with in the unittests for the code:

```
class LookupTableTests(object):                                                                   

    @classmethod                                                                                  
    def setup_class(cls):                                                                         
        """Load the lookup table instance used by the rest of the tests.                          
        """                                                                                       
        from fasteval import LookupTable                                                                                                             
        cls.lt = LookupTable.loadfile()                                                       

    @classmethod                                                                                  
    def teardown_class(cls):                                                                      
        """Free the lookup table instance used in these tests.                                    
        """                                                                                       
        cls.lt.close()                                                                            
        cls.lt = None
```

In the context of unit testing this makes a lot of sense to me, we set up the table once then run a bunch of tests and overall this saves a bunch of execution time (loading this table and doing the other initialization is slow).

However, outside of the unit tests I'm not sure of the best approach to make sure that the setup and cleanup is only performed once for the entire group of functions that use the lookup table.

The best idea I've had so far is to define a global that indicates if the setup has been performed or not. But this seems ugly to me and also raises the issue of cleanup not being properly dealt with if an unhandled exception is thrown somewhere. If I was doing this in c++ I think I would be trying to use some RAII principles and having the cleanup occur in a destructor to help me manage the resources but I don't know the proper way to do this in python.

What is the pythonic way to deal with a situation where you have a **group** of related functions that all require the same setup and cleanup? What sort of structure will this solution have?

Answer (score 1):

Use a class. Generate the lookup table in `__init__()`, create methods that use the table, and let the Python interpreter do the teardown.